# MySQL Distinct Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql

please excuse my lack of knowledge on this. I have limited experience with PHP and MySQL queries. I can do some basic queries, however, this is one I need to amend which is confusing me.

I have a query which pull all data for products that have awards assigned to them. However, if one product has multiple award, it shows that product multiple times. Ideally I want that product to be shown once.

I would look to apply a DISTINCT or UNIQUE value to the query, but the way the query is constructed, it doesn't appear to do anything.

The original query is the following:

```
<?php
                    $get_awards = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_posts 
 WHERE post_type = 'award' 
   AND post_status = 'publish' 
   AND YEAR(CAST(post_date AS DATE))=2009 
 GROUP 
    BY post_title 
 ORDER 
    BY post_date DESC
");
                    foreach ($get_awards as $award) {
                        $get_products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE post_type = 'ice-cream' AND post_status = 'publish' AND meta_key = 'awards' AND meta_value LIKE '%''".$award->ID."''%' OR post_type = 'frozen-yoghurt' AND post_status = 'publish' AND meta_key = 'awards' AND meta_value LIKE '%''".$award->ID."''%' OR post_type = 'sorbet' AND post_status = 'publish' AND meta_key = 'awards' AND meta_value LIKE '%''".$award->ID."''%'");
                        foreach ($get_products as $product) { ?>
```

I have tried a few versions of changing the SELECT * for SELECT DISTINCT etc but no joy. Would anyone mid giving me a few pointers please?

Comment: You have 1+n queries here. That's not good. You only need 1!!! Forget about the PHP for now and see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And the query you have is a complete mess, btw. Sorry to say, but you need to start over

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm sure I do, I inherited the code and find myself in a situation where I need to amend something I don't quite understand!

Answer (score 0):

If you * you select all the column so the distinct is unuseful

If you need  a distinct result you  should select explicitally only the column which you want the distinct value

```
Group by is for aggreagtion function and is not necessary  for distinct clause
```

so, assuminng the column you need are col1, col2, and col3 only  you should  use a select like

```
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col2 
    FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE post_type = 'award' 
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND YEAR(CAST(post_date AS DATE))=2009 
    GROUP BY post_title 
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
```